# AndroidStudio not recognizing .java file

Tags: android, android-studio

For some unknown reason, android studio decided not to recognize the .java file. Any idea how to resolve this?

I've tried deleting the file and recreating it, but it still results in the same issue. When recreating the file, some error came up and the file is automatically recreated

[image]

[image]

```
public class SubmitDealAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
...
}
```

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: What is it like in your system folder? Can you screenshot this?

Comment: @dummystreamer i tried that. didn't work

Comment: is that your orig package name? you might want to cover that too with blue line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that there's a wrong file association entry which associate that particular filename as a JavaFX file.

Look in the Preferences > Editor > File Types under Java files, the name of SubmitDealAsyncTask.java file is there and all I needed to do is to remove it.

Comment: I don't see the name(s) of any files under Preferences > Editor > File Types > Java. All I see is a textform at the bottom that says "Registered Patterns" and has "*.java" listed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could do this with adding "*.jvaa" to patterns and changing the file name to "blahblah.jvaa"

Answer (score 1):

Check your java file name and Class name.

```
class SubmitAsyncTask {}
```

should be saved in "SubmitAsyncTask.java"

Comment: updated with snippet. But i'm sure it has nothing to do with the filename and the Class name.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences > Editor > File Types > Java`, and then under each of the listed file types (Yes, unfortunately you have to look through all of them), and scroll down at the bottom of the to see if there is an entry for you file, and then click on it and the click the `-` sign.

Answer (score 0):

How did you include this file? I had problems just copying java classes in Android Studio, so maybe you might want to create a new java class and copy the content of the desired file into it. Then there should be no problem.

Comment: I created the file using Android Studio

Comment: did you include the package name at the top of the file ?

Comment: @dummystreamer yes.

Comment: at the time of creation of file where it asks for the class name did you give the .java explicitly? or just the name of the class?

Comment: I gave the name of the class.

Comment: Did this file work before? I mean did this occur out of nowhere or did it not work from the beginning? If second, can you create other files that are recognized correctly? And lastly (I am very new to Android Studio and apps) I read in a tutorial that Async Tasks should be declared inside an Activity class and from there start the doInBackground(). Maybe this helps...

Comment: @A.Hue It didn't work properly from the beginning. other file name works perfectly fine. strangely.

Comment: As I said, I don't really have based knowledge in Android apps, but I guess your problem is sourced in the name. Maybe try changing the name that it doesn't have "AsyncTask" in it, or as I said write this class inside of an Activity class (as mentioned before I read this in a tutorial and don't know if this is common practice, but for me it worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy all the code from this file and paste it inside your package(where you paint over you name with blue lines).
Android Studio will create new .java file for you there.

Answer (score 0):

@root  I created the class by right clicking on the package folder(com.example.tttt) in the project view and then new java class and naming it SubmitAsyncTask and then using the prototype you provided to create a dummy class and it worked for me as you can see below so if this doesn't solve it then you are missing something in the code its no longer an IDE problem :

[image]