# Android Studio not recognizing a single .kt file because of filename

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

I tried adding a new Kotlin class like I've done a hundred time in the past but for some odd reason, Android Studio doesn't recognize this file a a Kotlin class and can't be opened in Android Studio.

If I Refactor -> Rename the file to "Blah.kt", then it can be opened in Android Studio and if I rename it back to "AdData.kt" then this happens and it auto opens i n IntelliJ IDEA.

I've tried re-cloning the project, re-installing Android Studio, Clean/Rebuild, Invalidate caches and Restart and Restarting my computer, nothing fixes this...

[image]

Comment: try to open this file in `explorer/Finder` and then rename this file it may work

Comment: have you tried deleting and recreating it :)

Comment: you are not missing any dependencies or lines in the your gradle?? I had this problem when I has forgotten to write `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` in my gradle

Comment: @a_local_nobody yeah I've tried deleting/recreating multiple times, so weird that only this name "AdData" results in this behavior :(

Comment: Was able to solve this using information on this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021575/androidstudio-not-recognizing-java-file

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and solved by right click the file > File Type Override > choose kotlin file.